# How to insert a weblink QR code in caption or margin?

Tags: captions, marginpar, marginnote, qrcode

I want to insert a QR code image inside a figure caption (or in the margin). I then tried to write

```
\begin{figure*}[!ht]
\centering
\includegraphics[height=.45\linewidth]{im1.eps}
\hfill
\includegraphics[height=.45\linewidth]{im2.eps}
\caption{My caption. \protect\qrcode[hyperlink,height=0.5in]{http://www.ctan.org} }
\label{fig:coherence}
\end{figure*}
```

that produces the following error during the compilation :

```
    <QR code requested for "http\unskip \penalty \@M  ://www.ctan.org" in version 0
-M.>

Package xcolor Warning: Incompatible color definition on input line 271.

./Chapter6.tex:271: Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again> 
                   \unskip 
l.271 ...link,height=0.5in]{http://www.ctan.org} }
```

I suspect that the error is comming from an unsupported character, the ':', because when removed from the expression, I have

```
\caption{My caption \protect\qrcode[hyperlink,height=0.5in]{http//www.ctan.org}}
```

and the code compiles and produce a nice QR code image (the link is therefore 'http//www.ctan.org', not what I want).
Do you have an idea about how overcoming this problem ? I also tried to declare a robust command like that

```
\DeclareRobustCommand{\captionQR}{\qrcode[hyperlink,height=0.5in]{http://www.ctan.org}}
```

but with not much success.

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SE! Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem.

Comment: Your code works fine on my system - could you indeed provide an MWE to see if something interferes with the qrcode? Sometimes deleting the `.aux` file may help. It could also be some kind of version problem. I'm using `qrcode.sty 2015/01/08 v1.51`, `hyperref.sty 2012/11/06 v6.83m`, `xcolor.sty 2007/01/21 v2.11`, `pdflatex 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.16 (TeX Live 2015/Debian)`. (version numbers obtained with `\listfiles` before `\begin{document}`)

Answer (score 2):

`\marginnote` and `\marginpar` aren't a problem. But using `\qrcode` in a `\caption` can — depending on the class — result in a error messages, but you can avoid it using a box register:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{marginnote}
\usepackage{qrcode}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\newsavebox\captionqr
\usepackage{mwe}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[!ht]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=.45\linewidth]{example-image-a}
\hfill
\includegraphics[width=.45\linewidth]{example-image-b}
\savebox\captionqr{\qrcode[hyperlink,height=0.5in]{http://www.ctan.org}}
\caption[My caption]{My caption.\usebox\captionqr}
\label{fig:coherence}
\end{figure}
In the margin with
\verb|\marginnote|\marginnote{\qrcode[hyperlink,height=0.5in]{http://www.ctan.org}}.\lipsum[1]

In the margin with
\verb|\marginpar|\marginpar{\qrcode[hyperlink,height=0.5in]{http://www.ctan.org}}.\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

[image]

As an alternative try using package `caption`:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{qrcode}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{mwe}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[!ht]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=.45\linewidth]{example-image-a}
\hfill
\includegraphics[width=.45\linewidth]{example-image-b}
\caption[My caption]{My caption\protect\qrcode[hyperlink,height=0.5in]{http://www.ctan.org}}
\label{fig:coherence}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem are the `babel` shorthands. You can detokenize the second argument, so characters such as `:?!` won't trouble any longer.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}

\usepackage{qrcode}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcommand{\safeqrcode}[2][]{%
  \qrcode[#1]{\detokenize{#2}}%
}


\begin{document}


abc\marginpar{\safeqrcode[hyperlink,height=0.5in]{http://tex.stackexchange.com}}
\lipsum[1]

\begin{figure*}[!ht]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=.2\linewidth]{example-image.eps}
\hfill
\includegraphics[width=.2\linewidth]{example-image.eps}
\caption{Ma légende : avec deux points ? \safeqrcode[hyperlink,height=0.5in]{http://www.ctan.org}}
\label{fig:coherence}
\end{figure*} 

\lipsum\lipsum

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I made up a solution that seems to work while trying to provide an MWE. As I suspected, the error came from those ':'. I used at the time the package

```
\usepackage[french]{babel}
```

only. When replaced it by

```
\usepackage[english]{babel}
```

the code I was trying before worked fine. In order to conserve the french language as default in the document, I now include

```
\usepackage[english,french]{babel}
```

and when I want to place a QR code in the margin or caption I use

```
\selectlanguage{english}
\begin{figure}[!htbp]
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[width=.45\linewidth]{example-image-a}
\hfill
\includegraphics[width=.45\linewidth]{example-image-b}
\end{center}
\caption{My caption \protect\qrcode[hyperlink,height=0.5in]{http://www.ctan.org}} 
\label{fig:myfig}
\end{figure}
\selectlanguage{french}
```

Thank you two for your help, really useful ! :)

Comment: You'll get wrong spacing of colons and so on in your caption.